# POSTGRES: Getting different set of records when added a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

[image]

```
 $: select id from vehicles limit 5 offset 45
  -- Returns 

  -- 735
  -- 736
  -- 737
  -- 738
  -- 739

 $: select id, state from vehicles limit 5 offset 45;
  -- Returns

  -- 1381 | new
  -- 1327 | new
  -- 1304 | new
  -- 1382 | new
  -- 1317 | new
```

Even without adding any ordering/grouping, What could possibly be the reason why I am getting different set of records in my Postgresql when I added another column with 'id'?

PostgreSQL Ver - 12.6

Comment: I can't understand what you're talking about from your post....

Comment: @JasonGoemaat OP likely expects the same 5 rows from both queries, only with additional column from the second one. Adding the column changes which 5 rows they're getting, which *is* somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: I can't disagree with the thread getting closed - both the SQL standard and PostgreSQL-specific aspect has been covered in the threads listed. The one feature that would potentially differentiate this thread from those would be the path from *order-by-less order* breaking pagination (aim indicated by the use of `limit`+`offset`), to reliable sampling. Still, unless OP comes back to clarify that's in fact the intention and edits it in, it would be a questionable moderation practice for a 3rd party to alter/expand the scope of the question based on guesses.

Comment: `Even without adding any ordering` Why do you expect an order when you don't ask for any order?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Because, selecting a single column has some kind of ordering, and I think it is reasonable to expect the same set of records if we added an additional column as well.

Comment: No, that query with the single column doesn't have an order either. Without `order by`, there is no order. No fixed/guaranteed order that is. When using `limit` or `offset`, you are almost 100% sure you need an `order by` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Limit 5 offset 45` you're using effectively gives you *accidental* 5 rows unless you add an `order by` - without it the order is *not* guaranteed. PostgreSQL is free to fetch rows in any order it wants and write them in any order it wants. Even if you [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) by an index, forcibly rewriting a table to follow an order implied by a certain index, the choice how to read it back to you remains arbitrary, unless you specify the `order by` clause. [From the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html)

> If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.

You can experience *ordered reads* and grow to expect some *default sorting* behaviour, but unless you use an `order by` those are pretty much accidental and you can't rely on them keeping their order in the future.

---

If what you were after is in fact some kind of random 5 rows, but in a reliable and stable manner, I don't think you can achieve that easily. You'd have to order by everything in a cte/subquery to get a stable input, [`setseed()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) and then `order by random()` before cutting out your `limit 5 offset 45`.

This would sort of emulate the [`tablesample` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```
select id, state 
from vehicles tablesample system(1) repeatable(.2) 
limit 5 offset 45;
```

Even with a seed specified in `repeatable` (or `setseed()`) neither is truly repeatable: if the table changes between statements you will no longer get the same sample.

Comment: Right!  Random suggests a different order for each query.  Perhaps accidental is a better description.

Comment: @Andomar That's the word I've been looking for, thanks. Random, but unreliably random.

Comment: _Accident_ implies an incident has happened. Perhaps _arbitrary_ is even better?

Comment: @jarlh Hey, why not both. I've added that in as well. *Accidental* won with *random* because the latter could misleadingly suggest *different each time*. This one doesn't win with the previous champion but scores enough to get an honorable mention.